# A Question Related to Fubini's Theorem

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I was wondering if there is a integrable function $f: A \times B \to \mathbb{R}$ (where $A, B \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ are rectangles) such that
$$
\int\limits_{A \times B} f = \int\limits_{A}\int\limits_{B} f(x, y) \, dy \, dx
$$
but
$$
\int\limits_{B}\int\limits_{A} f(x, y) \, dx \, dy
$$
does not exist.

Comment: I don't think you can write the first line. The integral over $A\times B$ only makes sense in that way if the integral exists in either direction (and is equal).

Comment: I said $f$ is integrable so the first integral exists. Then I said such that the above equality holds (in which I am implying the existence of the second integral). So I think I can write the first line since I am assuming it is true.

Comment: If you're talking about Lebesgue integrability with respect to the product measure then $f$ being integrable on $A \times B$ is exactly the condition required for Fubini's theorem to apply, which gives existence and equality of both double integrals.

Comment: I didn't study Lebesgue integration yet.

Comment: That's the thing. You can't assign a value to $\int_{A\times B}f$ without saying that both integrals exist regardless of order and are equal.

Comment: I studied Fubini's theorem in Calculus on Manifolds by Spivak and it stated $\int\limits_{A \times B} f$ can exist without $\int\limits_{A}\int\limits_{B} f(x, y) \, dy \, dx$ existing. For the function $g(y) = f(c, y)$, we can have the set of points where $g$ is discontinuous on $B$ not be measure $0$ and still have the set of points where $f$ is discontinuous on $A \times B$ be measure $0$. Then the inner integral of $\int\limits_{A}\int\limits_{B} f(x, y) \, dy \, dx$ doesn't exist for $x = c$ so the whole integral doesn't exist. But $\int\limits_{A \times B} f$ still exists.

Comment: @PratyushSarkar: but $\{c\}$ has measure zero...

Comment: But $\int\limits_{B} f(x, y) \, dy$ doesn't exist for $x = c$ so the function $x \mapsto \int\limits_{B} f(x, y) \, dy$ isn't even defined for all $x \in A$ so how can you integrate it over $A$? You can work around by defining a random number for when $x = c$ but in Spivak's book he shows its not always possible.

Comment: Oh right, Riemann integration. In that case isn't your example exactly what you're looking for? Choose the discontinuity set to be the product of a point in $A$ with a rectangle in $B$. This has measure zero in $A \times B$ and in $A$ for each cross-section, but non-zero measure in $B$; so $\int_B \int_A$ should exist and coincide with $\int_{A \times B}$ while $\int_A \int_B$ doesn't exist.

Comment: You're right. Now I am wondering if both double integrals can exist and not be equal while the first one equals $\int\limits_{A \times B} f$.